# Demonstration of Rouché-Frobenius Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I'm looking for a demonstration of Rouché-Frobenius theorem. The hypothesis are the ones on the wikipedia page, but I'm looking for a demonstration that does not use Vector Space, or linear transformations. Only matrix algebra

Thanks!

PD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem

Comment: How would you change the statement "If there are solutions, they form an affine subspace of dimension $n-\operatorname{rank}A$ in $\Bbb R^n$", so to avoid the use of vector-space theory?

Comment: I don't understand, are you looking for a **proof** or an **example** (that is a demonstration)?

Comment: Im looking for a proof of the theorem. The course of Algebra i took includes Logic, Set Theory, Integer Numbers, Complex Numbers, Combinatorics, Relations and Functions, Cardinality and Matrix Algebra. Im going to learn Vector space and linear transformations in the next course, but i need that theorem, and didnt found it at any bibliography.